# NodeJS mongoose connections issue

Tags: node.js

I'm new at NodeJS and today started MongoDb section. I watch NodeJS videos (which recorded in 2016) , they connecting with mongoose. But it is not working correctly on me.

Codes :

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

    var mongoDB = "mongodb://localhost/nodedb";

    mongoose.connect(mongoDB,{ useNewUrlParser: true } ,function(err,err){
        if(err){
            console.log("Cant connect");
        }else{
            console.log("Connected to :" + mongoDB);
        }
    })
```

With this method I can connect. At least apperaing in Console :

`Connected to :mongodb://localhost/nodedb`

But there are some errors and one of them is :

```
Unhandled rejection MongoError: port must be specified
```

I write mongodb://localhost:27017/nodedb . But now couldn't connect. Where are issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify mongodb port, default one is 27017

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/

I use mongoose like this:

```
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/somename')
    .then((db)=>{console.log(`connected`);})
    .catch(error=>console.log(error));
```